# No matching member function for call to 'push_back'

Tags: c++

I have a matrix A(4,4) using newmat  and I want to put it in vector and then use push_back if a condition is valid and put it in double vector B. I am using this code :
Code :

```
vector <vector <double>>B;
vector <int>  temp;
for (int i=1;i <= A.ncols();++i)
   { for (int j=1;j < rank_of_A ; ++j)
      { temp(i)= A(i,j); }
    }

 for (int i = 1; i < A.ncols(); ++i)
     { if(did_i_pick_this_col[i])
        { B.push_back(temp(i));
          }
    }
```

I am getting the error " Type 'vector' does not provide a call operator"

Answer (score 2):

Here you try using `operator()` on a `vector<int>` - that is,`temp`:

```
temp(i)= A(i,j);
// and
B.push_back(temp(i));
```

It does not have such an operator.

You probably meant the subscript operator, `operator[]`:

```
temp[i]= A(i,j); 
// and
// note, you try pushing an `int` into a `vector<vector<double>>` here:
B.push_back(temp[i]); // this won't work
```

Even if you fix the above, your program would however have *undefined behavior* since `temp` is empty.

You could create it with `A.ncols() + 1` elements instead of creating it empty:

```
vector <int> temp(A.ncols() + 1);
```

The loop that goes from `1` to `A.ncols()` instead of from `0` to `A.ncols() - 1` may still be a mistake, but it's hard to say without seeing the rest of the code. I *suspect* that

```
for (int i = 1; i <= A.ncols(); ++i)
```

should really be:

```
for (int i = 0; i < A.ncols(); ++i)
```

in which case, `temp` should instead be created like this:

```
vector <int> temp(A.ncols());
```

Comment: Also,  OP is trying to push ```temp[i]```(Integer) to ```B``` which is a ```vector``` of ```vector<double>```.

Comment: @AshutoshAswal Nicely spotted. I added a comment about that